# Is there a better way to do this in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

```
  $(".exercise-name").click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).parent().siblings(".exercise-details").slideToggle('fast')
```

Basically in the following structure

```
.exercise
  .exercise-header
    .exercise-name
  .exercise-details
```

Is there anyway to get to exercise-details without having to traverse up through a parent and then it's siblings. A shortcut of sorts?

Comment: That seems good enough. If you know that it's the immediate next sibling you can use `next` => `$(this).parent().next().slideToggle('fast')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this:

```
$(".exercise-header, .exercise-name").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).siblings(".exercise-details").slideToggle('fast');
});
```

or this:

```
$(".exercise-name").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  $('.exercise').find(".exercise-details").slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: On your first example how would that work on .exercise-name, wouldn't that only be valid on .exercise-header?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `next()`..

```
  $(this).parent().next().slideToggle('fast');
```

if it is next immediate parent siblings... however i think the only way is to go to its parents first..